# Left Join Not Yielding Results

Tags: sql, impala

I have the below query where i need to have all records from first table1 and
corresponding value for table2.If value not there a NULL to be returned.
But i am getting only common records returned in the result.

```
select 

distinct s1.src_sys_id schema_nm,
to_date(CAST(CAST(s3.execn_ts AS BIGINT)/1000 AS TIMESTAMP)) as maxtime
from table1 s1

LEFT JOIN table2 s3 ON s1.src_sys_id = s3.src_sys_id

INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT src_sys_id, max(execn_ts) as maxtime
  FROM table2
  GROUP BY src_sys_id 
) s2 on s2.src_sys_id = s1.src_sys_id and s1.execn_ts = s2.maxtime
```

table1

```
schema_nm   
GA1P    
GG60    
GGDD    
GWY1    
GXO1    
GYY1    
GHOD
```

table2

```
schema_nm   execn_ts
GA1P    10/1/2018
GG60    10/2/2018
GGDD    10/3/2018
```

Current Results

```
schema_nm   maxtime
GA1P    10/1/2018
GG60    10/2/2018
GGDD    10/3/2018
```

Expected Results

```
schema_nm   maxtime
GA1P    10/1/2018
GG60    10/2/2018
GGDD    10/3/2018
GWY1    NULL
GXO1    NULL
GYY1    NULL
GHOD    NULL
```

Comment: [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) please

Comment: If `table1` and `table2` don't have matching `src_sys_id` values, the `LEFT JOIN` on `s3` will allow the `table1` row to be returned, but the `INNER JOIN` on `s2` will prevent it. Why would you do a left join to `table2` with `s3` but an inner join to the *same* table with `s2`? Makes no sense. Change `s2` to also be a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: i wanted to get the record with max time from table2

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your real question is to use window functions:

```
select s1.src_sys_id schema_nm,
       to_date(CAST(CAST(s3.execn_ts AS BIGINT)/1000 AS TIMESTAMP)) as maxtime
from table1 s1 left join
     (select s2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by s2.src_sys_id order by s2.execn_ts desc) as seqnum
      from table2 s2
     ) s2
     on s1.src_sys_id = s2.src_sys_id and s2.seqnum = 0;
```

The reason your query filters out rows is a bit tricky.  The `left join` is fine.  Even the `inner join` is fine . . . as far as it goes.  However, both joins are to the same table.  So, if a matching row doesn't exist for the first `join`, then a row doesn't exist for the second.

In other words, the `inner join` happens to filter out the same rows as the unmatched rows in the `left join`.

All that said, window functions are a better approach, although using `left join` again would also fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `LEFT JOIN` is redundant :

```
select s1.src_sys_id schema_nm,
       to_date(CAST(CAST(s2.execn_ts AS BIGINT)/1000 AS TIMESTAMP)) as maxtime
from table1 s1 left join (
     select s2.src_sys_id, max(s2.execn_ts) as execn_ts
     from table2 s2
     group by s2.src_sys_id
) s2 on s1.src_sys_id = s2.src_sys_id; 
        --s2.execn_ts = s1.execn_ts;
```

Comment: Thank you Yogesh. I rewrote the query but it does not consider the max time and returns multiple records in result.